# Safari textbox background issue

Tags: javascript, css, safari, mobile-safari

I have a textbox and instead of showing the regular 1px bordered layout, I am trying to apply a custom curved image as background for that..

For some reasons, the background is not applied correctly on desktop Safari as well as iPad Mobile Safari..It works fine in IE/FF..Below is the code;

```
<div class="inputBox"><input type="text" name="text1"></div>

#rightContent  .inputBox{
background:transparent url(/images/dp/search_screen/keyback.gif) no-repeat scroll center 6px;
border:0pt none;
float:left;
height:40px;
#height:37px;
margin-left:10px;
width:450px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#rightContent  .inputBox input{
padding:12px 8px 5px 12px; 
width:446px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px none;
background:transparent none no-repeat scroll center;
display: block;
/*outline: none;*/
height: 40px;
#height:37px;
#width: 430px;
#position: relative;
#left: 2px;
#padding:11px 0px 8px;
}
```

Below are the screenshot

IE/FF:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what's going wrong in Safari?

Comment: ok..I have added the screenshots.

Comment: Please provide some other solution..Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'transparent' from your background that contains the image.

If that doesn't work, it looks like there's something else controlling Safari's text boxes. Are you using a CSS reset?

EDIT/

Enable the Developer menu in Safari. Right click on the text field and click Inspect Element. See where that border is coming from.

Or to take a quicker route, ad `!important` at the end of all your selectors.

Comment: He needs the transparent, because the background-image is part transparent (corners).

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can have a transparent background image work just fine in all browsers without that. The `transparent` is completely 100% unnecessary and Safari could be interpreting it wrong. However, again, that border looks as though something else is controlling text fields in Safari. Make sure you know what you're talking about before you start voting down.

Comment: I would try that first: [http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/). If that doesn't work, add the `!important` statements and that will gridlock them. But again, if you really want to find the root of the problem, inspect the element.

Comment: I see something -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; from Inspect element..Again this seems to be generated by Safari.

Comment: CSS reset should help you here. If it doesn't, post a link to the actual website page you're having an issue with and I'll find it :)

Comment: ok..Is it possible through the Developer to attach the CSS and test on the page?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can attach CSS but you can certainly edit it by double clicking whatever it is you want to edit.